# Grouping results in Select2

Tags: jquery-select2

Is it possible somehow to **group results** in a Select2 component when it's not using `<select>` tag, but `<input type="hidden">`, and results are provided as "data" option in configuration object?

```
var select2Options = {
  data: {
    results: myArrayOfResults
  }
};
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Yes, the `results` objects support a `children` attribute...

so for example:

```
var select2Options = {
  data: {
    results: [
      {text: "My shiny group", children: [
          {id: 1, text: "My shiny item"}, 
          {id: 2, text: "My shiny item2"}
      ]}
    ]
  }
};
```

Comment: Well it's quite long time I used it lastly... I don't know if is it working with the current version of Select2.

Comment: worked for me now, but title must be changed by text. thanks anyway, after few hours rounding around, I get this stuff working. I'm sure your post here helped me yet!

Comment: to keep it up-to-date, maybe you can edit the answer just adding the possibility of text instead TITLE :)

Comment: I see, you are right, I've simplified it, thank you.

Comment: FYI: Children can be stacked so you can build a tree-like hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

For ajax data loading with group and data work for me using,

```
$arrFinal = array(array("name"=>"My shiny group 1",
"children"=>array(array("id"=>1,"name"=>"My shiny item 11"),array("id"=>2,"name"=>"My shiny item 12"))
),array("name"=>"My shiny group 2",
"children"=>array(array("id"=>1,"name"=>"My shiny item 21"),array("id"=>2,"name"=>"My shiny item 22"))
)
);
die(json_encode(array("result" => $arrFinal)));

if formatResult: ratioFormatResult then,
function ratioFormatResult(row) {
// Here, you will get both group ("My shiny group 1") as well as data("My shiny item11") as row .
}
```

To make group selectable use id field along with name in group.