# Passing already grouped options to angular ui-select

Tags: angularjs, ui-select2

Is it possible somehow to pass already groped option to angular [ui-select](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select), like for jquery select2 [Grouping results in Select2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17611174/grouping-results-in-select2)? For me not possible use `group-by` because some options don't have parent.

```
[     
      {id: 3, text: "Item name 3 without parent."},
      {text: "Group name", children: [
          {id: 1, text: "Item name 1"}, 
          {id: 2, text: "Item name 2"}
      ]}
    ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably solved this already, but for future reference:

When some of elements do not have a parent, `select.ui` will create a nameless group for them and show them at the beginning of list. So you can use group-by in this case.

Comment: Ha, yes, since `ui-select` 0.9.6 it works properly. Thank you.